# Regular expression to Get Extension - .net

Tags: .net, regex, sharepoint

Environment - SharePoint Workflow (.net tech)

Trying to get extension of a file name (sometime it's doc or docx or dwg or xlsx).

I got this `\..+`  or this `\.[^\.]+$` to give me the file name. I need another expression that will give me the extension. I guess I need an expression that will look for the last period and give me the string.

Comment: `.net file extension` in google returned [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx)...

Comment: Have you considered a file with several extensions `foo.tar.gz` ? I think a simple split on the first dot would do the job.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Path.GetExtension(fileName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) instead of creating regex - it looks last `.` in file name and returns substring with extension.

UPDATE: If it has to be regex, then try `\.[0-9a-z]+$`

Comment: Thanks but it has to be regular expression.

Comment: @torres strange.. Well, you can use pattern `\.[0-9a-z]+$` it selects text after last dot

Comment: myfilename.docx and the expression gives me myfilename instead of docx. hmm

Comment: when I use this regex I get the file name \.[0-9a-z]*.$ . I just need to get the extension without the period. hmm

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like:

```
@"(?<=\.)([^\\/.]*)$"
```

It means: `([^\\/.]*)` any non-dot non-path character in any number, followed by end-of-the-string `$`. The non-dot characters must be preceded by a dot `(?<=\.)` that won't be captured. (so filename without extension are captured as having blank extension)

Note the escaping of the `\` inside the `[]`

some funny test cases:

```
C:\My.Path\Filename
C:\My.Path\Filename.ext
C:\My.Path\Filename.ext.ext2
..\Filename
..\Filename.ext
```

Tester: http://regexr.com?361pu

I'll add that `Path.GetExtensions` *is* the right instrument to do this work.

Comment: I need to grab the extensions. The syntax above is not giving me the extension instead I get the entire file name with ext.

Comment: When I use this (?<=\.)([^\\/.]*)$ I get filename with dot

Comment: I think SharePoint workflow uses XML but per Microsoft regex is .net based. I am bit confused.

Comment: can it return the extension like docx or doc or pdf. for me it returns file name with dot. for example the regex returns my documents. instead of pdf

Comment: It (?<=\.)(.*) worked with extract instead of replace regex. Thanks for your help.